# How to configure spi in the driver file insted of giving configuration in the application

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to write a test driver for `mcspi` and want to give all configuration in my driver file (instead of using user space application I want to use driver as a test driver and want to create .ko) and want to pass all configuration to the `mcspi` controller.

The configurations like chip_select, mode, speed, bits etc., Basically all these configurations I want to use for my test driver to check functionality of FIFO mode in the `mcspi`. I have already enabled FIFO in the `mcspi` but I want to check its functionality.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why cant you do something you want. I think you can pass the configuration by set up parameters using module_param

Answer (score 0):

Adding on what @sunnyleevip suggested: another "standard" way to configure your driver would be to expose the params of interest via the /proc or the /sys filesystems.
You can find all the details in [Linux Device Driver](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on @sergico and @sunnyleevip, you could also use [device tree](http://devicetree.org/Main_Page) to pass configuration data to the driver.  The SPI bus master driver (since the 2.6.30s and all of the 3.x kernels) already are pretty devicetree supportive, so there might not be much more to do to get it to work.

Comment: Device Tree is arch dependent.  For instance x86 does does not use the Device Tree.   *"the 2.6.30s and all of the 3.x kernels) already are pretty devicetree supportive"* -- That is not true for ARM.

Comment: @sawdust:  au contraire.  I have done 70% of my ARM work using device tree, 100% since the beginning of 2014.  It works, but it is poorly documented.

Comment: Good for you, but I don't believe that you could have used a 2.6.x kernel. DT support only began in mainline 3.1 with a few ARM boards. You seem to persist making blanket or vague statements.